# Is the "Activity" portion of the User page malfunctioning?

Tags: bug, design, user-profile-page

Currently when I visit my user page and select `Activity` and then `Summary`, the vote count for the `Answers` portion appears to be the vote count for the *question* rather than for my answer. Was there a recent update to the site that caused this? I don't believe the issue was present yesterday.

The screen shot below shows the issue. The vote counts are for the questions, not for my answers. The time also represents the time the question was posted, not the answer. If I select the `Answers` tab on the left of the screen the correct information appears.

[image]

Comment: Yes. The entire Summary portion has been reverted back to a two-column layout (from one at first). The current Activity page layout and design is very fluid.

Comment: Corresponding post on [meta.se]: [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/168244)

Comment: No, the OP's question is not about the responsiveness. But I don't get this bug: As for today, when I check the votes for the Answers in the Summary section, these are indeed the votes for the answers and also the time is the time when the answer was posted.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: This issue was corrected after about a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Activity section on the user profile page is currently very fluid as it's undergoing a heavy redesign. This redesign was rolled out on Dec 7, 2021.

Here is [a 5-minute tour](https://youtu.be/1hPjjvp4b8I) outlining the original redesign, but [feedback from other network users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/168244) have been quite negative in general. So, expect things to change (for better or for worse) within the next little while. Also consider providing feedback (like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)) on the original Meta post, as the changes are being made network-wide.

Reference: [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/168244)